# Анимация в Android

Tags: java, android

Являюсь суперновичком, поэтому и задаю этот вопрос.

Хочу реализовать такой механизм:

Есть кнопка, при нажатии на которую изображение(допустим, квадрата) движется на какое-то расстояние в сторону. При повторном нажатии это изображение снова движется на то же расстояние в ту же сторону и так далее.

Но у меня получилось реализовать только первую часть - при повторном нажатии на кнопку ничего не происходит.

Код:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private AnimationDrawable mAnimationDrawable;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageView square = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.square);
    square.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animationlist);
    mAnimationDrawable = (AnimationDrawable)square.getBackground();

    final Button btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mAnimationDrawable.start();
        }
    });
}
```

Animation-list:

```
<animation-list android:oneshot="true"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:duration="30"  android:drawable="@drawable/square_one" />
<item android:duration="30"  android:drawable="@drawable/square_two" />
```

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При клике на кнопку выдолжны понимать какой раз на нее тыкнули в простейшем случае создайте булеву переменную в поле активити.

```
boolean flag = true;
```

Так же у Вас должно быть две анимации: одна движет вправо, другая влево.
Затем в листнере кнопке вам нужно вызывать соответствующую анимацию, не забываем каждый раз инвертировать флаг.

```
    btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (flag) {
             animationToRight.start();
        } else {
             animationToLeft.start();
        }
        flag = !flag;
    }
    });
```